# auto start programm doesn't work like manual start

Tags: c, database, sqlite, raspbian, autostart

I wrote a program in C that automatically creates a table in a *sqlite3* database and prints every second values in it. The program works fine, when I start it manually in a terminal.
However it doesn't work correctly when I run the program on startup by executing it in */etc/rc.local*.
When I reboot, the program starts (I see it in the list of processes) but it doesn't create any table nor writes values in it.
I tried using *sudo* in front of my command and *&* at the end of my command but it doesn't change anything.
I don't have a clue about this problem but I have to get this program work on startup.

That's my *rc.local* file.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

./home/pi/Desktop/RPi_Arduino_Project/rpi5_1 &


exit 0
```

Could it be the DBMS that hasn't started yet at this point of startup?
Is there a possibility to start a terminal and execute it in there instead of execute it directly from *rc.local* (because that is working)?

Edit: my program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include "rs232.h"

#define BUF_SIZE 128    //eventually needs to be bigger

char table_name[256];


int openCOMport(int cport_nr1, int bdrate, char mode[]){
    if(RS232_OpenComport(cport_nr1, bdrate, mode)){
        printf("Can not open comport 1\n");
        return(0);
    }
    sleep(2);
    return(1);
}

int saveinfile(sqlite3 *db, double *output, int rowlength, int newfile){

    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm *ts = localtime(&t);
    char sql[512];
    char *errMsg;
    char columnnames[256];

    char date_time[256];
    int j = 0;

    //control terminal output
    printf("%02d-%02d-%04d %02d:%02d:%02d ",ts->tm_mday,ts->tm_mon+1,ts->tm_year+1900,ts->tm_hour,ts->tm_min,ts->tm_sec);
    for(j=0; j<rowlength; j++){
        printf(" %.2f ", output[j]);            
    }

    if(newfile == 1){
        sprintf(table_name,"Gas_Sensor_test_%04d_%02d_%02dT%02d_%02d_%02d",ts->tm_year+1900,ts->tm_mon+1,ts->tm_mday,ts->tm_hour,ts->tm_min,ts->tm_sec);
        printf("Table Name: %s\n",table_name);

        //Create Table and write header
        sprintf(sql, "CREATE TABLE %s (Date date    NOT NULL, Time time NOT NULL, HCHO1 float, HCHO2    float, HCHO3    float, FinFlow1 float, FinFlow2 float, PRIMARY KEY(Date, Time));",table_name);

        //SQL execution
        if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, 0, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK ){
            printf("SQL error: %s\n", errMsg);
            return(0);
        }
    }

    //insert new rows and print time and date 
    sprintf(sql,"INSERT INTO %s (Date, Time) VALUES ('%04d-%02d-%02d', '%02d:%02d:%02d');",table_name,ts->tm_year+1900,ts->tm_mon+1,ts->tm_mday,ts->tm_hour,ts->tm_min,ts->tm_sec);
    //printf("SQL Befehl: %s \n",sql); //just control output
    if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, 0, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK ){
        printf("SQL error: %s\n", errMsg);
        return(0);
    }

    //Write data in table
    sprintf(sql,"UPDATE %s SET HCHO1 = %f, HCHO2 = %f, HCHO3 = %f WHERE Date = '%04d-%02d-%02d' AND Time =  '%02d:%02d:%02d';",table_name, output[1], output[2],output[3],ts->tm_year+1900,ts->tm_mon+1,ts->tm_mday,ts->tm_hour,ts->tm_min,ts->tm_sec);
    if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, 0, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK ){
        printf("SQL error: %s\n", errMsg);
        return(0);
    }

    return (1); 
}


int main(){
  //port parameters initialization
  int cport_nr1=16;                     // /dev/ttyUSB0
  int bdrate=2000000;                       //Baudrate
  char *out;                            //outputpointer
  char delimiter[] = ";";               //Trennzeichen
  char mode[]={'8','N','1',0};          //8 data bits, no parity, 1 stop bit
  char str_recv[BUF_SIZE];              //recv data buffer
  double sensor_value[20];              //array for storing the sensor values
  int i;


  if(openCOMport(cport_nr1, bdrate, mode) == 0){            //open COMport
    return (0);
  }

  //create database object
  sqlite3 *db;

  if(sqlite3_open("sensor_tests.db", &db)){
      printf("Can't open database");
      return(0);
  }

  int new = 1;
  while(1) {
    int n = RS232_PollComport(cport_nr1, str_recv, (int)BUF_SIZE);
    if(n > 0){
        str_recv[n] = '\0';             //always put a "null" at the end of a string!
        //printf("Received %i bytes: '%s'\n", n, (char *)str_recv);
    }
    else if (n == 0){
      continue;
    }
    else{
      printf("Error while receiving Data");
      return (0);
    }

    out = strtok(str_recv, delimiter);
    i = 0;

    while(out != NULL){
        //printf("String RECV: %s\n",str_recv);
        sensor_value[i]= atof(out);         //converting string to double
        if(sensor_value[i] < 0){
            printf("Sensor value out of range");
        }
        out = strtok(NULL, delimiter);      //next part of input string
        printf("Sensor %d: %.2f   \n",i+1,sensor_value[i]);
        i++;
    }

    double *psensor_value = sensor_value;
    if(saveinfile(db, psensor_value, i, new) == -1){
        printf("Error while writing data in file!");
        break;
    }
    new = 0;
  }
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe add debug statements in your program and see where it fails? Check if the connection to the DB is successful otherwise probably the DB daemon did not start yet.

Comment: @amine.ahd Please make that an answer. I bet an upvote that it is the solution, it is at least worth considering for future users with a similar problem.

Comment: Do you need the "." (dot) in front of your path?

Comment: @amine.ahd do you know how to check if the connection was successful?

Comment: @yty yes it is necessary.

Comment: Show your program.

Comment: I added my program and also tried starting my program up with a *systemd* service 30 secs after os startup. But it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

So I will convert my comment to an answer as per @Yunnosch advice.
First of all, the answer is trying to give tips on how to generally debug this kind of issues.
First of all I would advice reading about `rc.local` and priorities, you can for example select which daemons are started after which and you can inside your script check if the daemon exists.

Into your program, its a good practice to always check the return value of functions as this gives you a quick idea what went wrong.

For example to check if the connection is successful to the DB(assuming you are using sqlite3 interface) you can check what `sqlite3_open()` [returns](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) with a nice [description](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html) of all error codes. From here you can rule out if the connection is successful or not and move to the next function and so on until you find the root issue.

Comment: I do catch errors. If (sqlite3_open()){} is returning an error it will terminate the program. But when I reboot it runs. So therefor I don't think that this is the root cause.